# GUI Shoes not implementing a method call?

Tags: ruby, shoes

I am trying to build a shoes app but for some reason a method (print_statement) I am calling on a class instance isn't doing anything.  I can see that the instance has been created (with the method inside ready to use) in the shoes app but when I call the method nothing seems to happen (it works fine in IRB).

Shoes code:

```
      `flow(margin: 15) do 
         button "Print Statement" do
          @statement = Statement.new(@account)
          para @statement.print_statement
         end
       end`
```

The instance method within Statement is:

```
def print_statement
  i = 0
  print_array = []
  while i < account.transaction_record.length
    transaction = account.transaction_record[i]
    transaction_object = transaction[0]
    print_array.push( "Date: #{transaction_object.created_date} " \ 
    "Transaction Type: #{transaction_object.class} " \
    "Amount: #{transaction_object.value} Balance: #{transaction[1]}" )
    i += 1
  end
  return print_array
end
```

A call to an attr_reader method on the same instance works but not the call to the print_statement method (not the most elegant method ever!) even though tested and working in both RSpec and IRB.

Comment: What is the error message? Just saying "It didn't work" isn't helpful.

Comment: @thesecretmaster - There is no error it just simply fails to work.  It will successfully display the 'object' via the method call '@statement.account' but '@statement.print_statement' does nothing, no error, no output, nothing.  I'm assuming it's a Shoes thing as an array is out put if this is done in IRB.

Comment: Can you post the current output and the expected output (screenshots)?

Comment: @thesecretmaster - The problem seems to have resolved itself by turning the whole Shoes application off and on again.  Before when I had changed code within my app I would close down the current running program window, open it up afresh through the Shoes menu bar at the top.  However, on this occasion I quit the Shoes application altogether and opened it up again and then opened up the project and all of the code seemed to work.  Not sure why this is?

Comment: shouldiblamecaching.com

Answer (score 0):

Up until now when I had updated code within my project code I would simply close the Shoes window that was running the project, open it afresh and the code updates would all be there and working, up until this issue occurred.

It seems to have resolved itself after I quit the whole Shoes application from my Mac dock and relaunched it then opened up my project again within Shoes.